# how does jasmine compare complex objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, jasmine

In jasmine, how does comparison helpers such as `expect(a).toEqual()` work in the source code?
Does it check by ducktyping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you are not sure, look into the [source code](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine):

[image]

(taken from [Learn to Read the Source, Luke](http://blog.codinghorror.com/learn-to-read-the-source-luke/)).

I won't quote the actual implementation (it's quite big), but here is the [underlying util function](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/4be20794827a63ca5295848c58ffc478624ee4dc/src/core/matchers/matchersUtil.js#L77) performing the check.

FYI, it is actually adapted from [`_.isEqual()`](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) and uses stacks to perform deep object and array comparisons.

Note that you can extend the jasmine equality check by adding your [custom equality testers](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_equality.html).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer

`toEqual` compares all the properties of both objects and returns true if the corresponding values are equal.

The long answer

You can follow the trail of [`toEqual`](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/4be20794827a63ca5295848c58ffc478624ee4dc/src/core/matchers/toEqual.js) in the source code and eventually land [here in the `eq` method](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/4be20794827a63ca5295848c58ffc478624ee4dc/src/core/matchers/matchersUtil.js#L77) which gives the gritty details...(and I quote the source: 'lovingly adapted from [isEqual in Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual)')